# NSMutableArray Display Null Value in Table View

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios5, nsmutablearray

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

self.detailView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)    style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.detailView.dataSource = self;
self.detailView.delegate = self;
self.detailView.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.detailView];
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Routes", nil);
self.detailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString  *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chennai&destination=Madurai&sensor=false"];
NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSError* error;
NSMutableDictionary* parsedJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data              options:kNilOptions  error:&error];
NSArray *allkeys = [parsedJson allKeys];

for(int i = 0; i < allkeys.count; i++){

if([[allkeys objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"routes"]){
NSArray *arr  = [parsedJson objectForKey:@"routes"];
NSDictionary *dic   = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *legs = [dic objectForKey:@"legs"];
for(int i = 0;  i < legs.count; i++){
NSArray *stepsArr = [[legs objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"steps"];
for (int i = 0; i < stepsArr.count; i++) {
NSLog(@"HTML INSTRUCTION %@", [[stepsArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"html_instructions"]);
NSLog(@"############################");
[self.detailArray addObject:[[stepsArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"html_instructions"] ];
                }
            }

        }

    }        
});    
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [self.detailArray count];

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 5.0f, 300.0f, 30.0f)];
label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.detailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
label.numberOfLines = 3;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:(12.0)];
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[label release];

return cell;
}
```

i want to display the detailArray in the Table View.But it display null values in Table View.But in NSlog it display current values.The detailArray having set of direction values. is any possible to display in TableView.if i give constant value in displayArray its show correctly in TableView. please help me if Any one know.i am waiting for your valuable Answers,Thanks.

Comment: try adding a breakpoint right after you've added values to detailArray to check if detailArray does have values in it.

Comment: also why you set delegate to tableview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?? and also why reload tableview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?? remove this two lines from `cellForRowAtIndexPath: method` tableView.delegate = self; and [self.detailView reloadData];

Comment: Anila detailArray having values correcting.

Comment: paras i delete that two lines but no change.

Comment: @vishnusivabalan::: Add `NSLog(@"%@",self.detailArray)` at the end of `viewDidLoad`. Also `[self.detailView reloadData];`again calls the tableview delegate methods. So, probably an infinite loop

Comment: Abhishek: its shows 0 value. if i use NSLog in next to detailarray means it shows 20 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

After add whole data (values) in after retain it and reload TableView like bellow...

```
[self.detailArray retain];
[self.detailView reloadData];
```

i am sure your problem solved... :)

Comment: i delete that two lines but no change.please help me.

Comment: set label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; and also set text Test in every lable try it out

Comment: so i think you method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not called do this thing just add this line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method with `NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath Called");` tell me this line print or not ok..

Comment: it didn't print.if i give constant value in detailarray means it print.

Comment: yes then its problem with your array dude.. i am sure.. just retain that array after you add value init like [self.detailArray retain];

Comment: where i have to give this two lines.in the end of viewdidload?.

Comment: Thank you so much paras.the is running.you are so Guinness boss.i want to make a contact with you.vishnusivabalan.sp@gmail.com this is my mail id.pls pls pls send ur mail id.

Comment: @vishnusivabalan accept and upvote the answer mate if its helpful to you... :)

Comment: how to upvote paras.really i am new to this.tell me definitely i'll do for you.

Comment: i think you will give me upvote after 15 reputation so now you can not give upvote to any answer or quetion.. :)

Comment: @vishnusivabalan now you can give me upvote from up arrow new my answer's top left corner.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove  `[self.detailView reloadData];` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. and also remove `tableView.delegate = self;` in same method.

and remember `[super viewDidLoad];` must write at top of `viewDidLoad`.

**Edit** 
 just change your four array as below.

```
   NSArray *legs=(NSArray *)[dic objectForKey:@"legs"];
   NSArray *arr  = (NSArray *)[parsedJson objectForKey:@"routes"];
   NSArray *legs = (NSArray *)[dic objectForKey:@"legs"];
   NSArray *stepsArr = (NSArray *)[[legs objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"steps"];
```

Comment: i delete that two lines but no change.please help me.

Comment: print parsedJson what it prints?

Comment: it display the full details between two routes.eg:(lat,long,dis,route).i extract route values from this and store in detailArray.

Comment: if it not working then also change  NSArray *allkeys =(NSArray *) [parsedJson allKeys];

Comment: i changed for all no change.its not call the  method cellForRowAtIndexPath.if i use constant value in detailarray means it call the  method cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting detailView delegate and datasource 2 times in viewDidLoad. Please format the code first then it will be easy for us to describe the problem.

```
self.detailView.dataSource=self;
self.detailView.delegate=self;
self.detailView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)    style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.detailView.dataSource = self;
self.detailView.delegate = self;
```